# What tactic configurations makes solving Quantifier logic faster in general?

Tags: logic, constraints, z3, smt, z3py

I am using Microsoft Z3 SMT solver. The current performance bottleneck resides in the some quantifier logical formulas.

Is there any tactics tuning suggestion for quantifiers?

Comment: In my experience, the most important aspect of reasoning about quantifiers (at least foralls) are triggers/patterns. Make sure that ever forall (in positive position) has well-picked triggers. The Z3AxiomProfiler (part of Microsoft's C verifier VCC) can help to identify triggering problems.

Comment: Thanks, Malte. I don't know anything about the triggers/patterns and how to configure them in Z3 (preferably using python api). Is there any material you could point me to so I can learn about it?

Comment: Nothing z3py-specific, but the following resources discuss patterns:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide,  
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/moskal/pdf/prtrig.pdf,  
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leino/papers/rmkrml183.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Malte. You are such a lifesaver!